# mORMot responding to HTTP requests on port 80 instead of IIS

Tags: delphi, iis, mormot

The website of our company is running on IIS 7.5, recently and without any modifications in the configuration, the website start to give us the error 404, here is a picture of the error :

[image]

the website work fine with HTTPS and HTTP on every port **except the port 80**, and we have never used MorMot

Do you have any ideas where this problem comes from ?

Comment: So you can't find process on your computer that uses port 80? Try one of this solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198

Comment: I tried , only the process 'system' use port 80

Comment: Clearly something has been changed. Find out what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a registration mechanism for URI on Windows, when using `http.sys`. It is [a kernel/system component, handling HTTP/HTTPS requests](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_88).
This registration is shared by IIS and other programs using `http.sys`, like *WCF* or *mORMot* projects.

From the HTML returned, there is clearly a mORMot-powered executable running on the server, which is bound to port 80. You have to identify this program and fix its configuration, to use another port or another sub-URI on port 80, to share it with IIS.

One big benefit of `http.sys` - in addition to its performance - is that you can share URIs on the same (sub)domain between executables, but you need to register the sub-URI. This is a standard mechanism under Windows - please check [this reference page for instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https).

Another possibility may be to use IIS as reverse proxy, and run the mORMot-powered executable on a local non-routed port, if you have troubles with `http.sys` configuration (which is not easy).

Comment: You're right the problem was in the url reservation, thanks